# Socket Timeout exception on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, retrofit2

Application suddenly can't access internet connection only on any version emulator(earlier it could, and i didn't make a change code of network). Moreover, in other emulator's apps connection fine. On mobile devices app's network works . For what reason could it be?

Comment: Android version of emulator?

Comment: api 17, 19, 28, 29